# Como imprimir el resultado de dos funciones distintas al mismo tiempo?

Tags: javascript, array, funciones

Alguien sabe como se puede ejecutar dos funciones al mismo tiempo y que el resultado salga uno al lado del otro.y que dichas funciones nada tengan que ver.
Por ejemplo dentro de una función exista  la suma de dos valores y la otra la multiplicacion de otros dos valores. ( Es solo un ejemplo).
Lo que deseo es con un input tipo button ejecutar dos funciones al mismo tiempo y que me salga el resultado de una al lado de la otra  ( concatenado )...
Alguien sabe como hacer eso ?...
Gracias

Comment: Crea una tercera función que llame a las dos anteriores y haga la concatenación de los resultados de estas funciones.

Comment: Pon algo de código para entender el contexto. Cuando dices "al mismo tiempo" es una noción en programación que es algo compleja y no creo que ese sea tu caso. Me parece que tu intentas algo como mifuncion1() + mifuncion2() que se puede hacer perfectamente

Answer (score 0):

Si, podes juntar los resultados de ambas funciones en una cadena y agregarla como contenido de un Div usando textContent. Solo hay que seleccionar el boton y el div, y agregar el evento al onclick boton

```
const sum = (a, b)  => { return a + b };
const multiply = (a, b)  => { return a * b };

document.getElementById("button").onclick = () => {
  document.getElementById("display").textContent = `${sum(5, 10)} ${multiply(5, 10)}` // concatenamos con plantillas literales
}
```